# Autoit. Array of HWND

Tags: autoit

I am totally new to Autoit and i am wondering, if there is a way to create an array of HWND?
I need to store them and go through each in cycle.

```
#include <Array.au3>

Local $NotepadList
Local $NotepadHWNDList

$NotepadList= WinList('Notepad')

For $i = 1 To $NotepadList[0][0]
   Local $tmpHWND = $NotepadList[$i][1]
   ConsoleWrite($tmpHWND & @CRLF)
   _ArrayAdd($NotepadHWNDList, $NotepadList[$i][1])
Next
```

Resulting `$NotepadHWNDList` is empty, though there are 3 instance in Console output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I run that code above, nothing will be output to the console because `$NotepadList[0][0]` is 0. This is because by default, window matching functions like `WinList` work by matching the first part of the window title, not a substring. To fix this, add

```
Opt("WinTitleMatchMode", 2)
```

at the top of your program in order to enforce substring matching in window titles.

In addition, the `_ArrayAdd` function won't work because `$NotepadHWNDList` is not defined as an array. To define it as an array, you need to add an index specifier. So change your variable definition to

```
Local $NotepadHWNDList[0]
```

You can use a value of 0 since you don't know how many windows you will have, and the array will automatically expand.

So now your entire program will look like this:

```
#include <Array.au3>

Opt("WinTitleMatchMode", 2)

Local $NotepadList
Local $NotepadHWNDList[0]

$NotepadList = WinList("Notepad")

For $i = 1 To $NotepadList[0][0]
   Local $tmpHWND = $NotepadList[$i][1]
   ConsoleWrite($tmpHWND & @CRLF)
   _ArrayAdd($NotepadHWNDList, $NotepadList[$i][1])
Next

; Display all array items
_ArrayDisplay($NotepadHWNDList)
```

Comment: Thank you! Actually in code, there is "Untitled - Notepad".
So the problem was in declaration of an array. And now it's solved! :)

Answer (score 2):

By default, AutoIt will have WinList match window titles from the start of the title.

And the Notepad app puts "Notepad" at the end of the title.

So you'll have windows named "Untitled - Notepad" and "test.txt - Notepad".  AutoIt won't find them with `WinList ('Notepad')` because it's looking for "Notepad" at the start of the title.

The thing to do is to tell it to match on partial window title.

If you add this near the top of your script (i.e. somewhere before the `WinList` instruction):

```
Opt("WinTitleMatchMode", 2) ;1=start, 2=subStr, 3=exact, 4=advanced, -1 to -4=Nocase
```

It should do the trick.

AutoIt WinList reference:
https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/WinList.htm - note the link to "Title special definition"

Discussion of Window Matching modes: 
https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/windowsadvanced.htm

Reference for setting these options:
https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/AutoItSetOption.htm#WinTitleMatchMode